# grails method missing exception when trying to find null value in domain

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

According to the grails doc (found at http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#finders)

```
Category.findAllByParentCategoryIsNull()
```

is the proper way to find a Category who's ParentCategory is null.

here's my category domain class

```
class Category {

    String name
    Category parentCategory

    static constraints = {
        name unique:true
        parentCategory nullable:true
    }
}
```

for some reason, I'm getting a method missing exception

```
Caused by MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static groovy.lang.Category.findAllByParentCategoryIsNull() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

Comment: What version of Grails?

Comment: If you are running unit test/spec then you have to use [`@Mock(Category)`](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/testing.html#unitTesting) to make dynamic finders available in unit test env.

Comment: this is under run-app

Comment: Got it. You are referring to `groovy.lang.Category` as seen from the exception. Rectify package appropriately. :)

Comment: @dmahapatro Good eyes (:

Comment: @dmahapatro If you put that as a solution I'll be sure to accept it

Comment: @JoshuaMoore LOL. You have been like that as well, many times. Glad to see you active in SO. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`groovy.lang.Category` is referred instead of `Category` Domain class which would be in a different package.

Rectifying the package in the class where `Catergory` is used would resolve this issue.